# How to redirect traffic from subdomain to main domain

Tags: apache-httpd, htaccess

I have a `demo.domain.com` and `domain.com`
they both show the same information and point to the same folder.

How can I redirect all `demo.domain.com` visitors to `domain.com`?

Comment: I see the htaccess tag, but you should specify your HTTPD so no one assumes.

Comment: There is a complete answer on stack overflow about this. Look [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597474/use-htaccess-to-redirect-all-traffic-from-subdomain-to-domain-without-maintainin?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the HTTPD is apache:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.* [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/ [L]
```